# I can't re-apply the select_tool more than once without affecting the resulting process on the first select

Tags: python

I created a simple selection tool to determine the pivot_point of the selected range, we take it as a starting point for the 'update_chart_2' function to pulles data frome MySQL dataset , The problem is that I can't re-apply the select_tool more than once without affecting the resulting process on the first select , I tried manually assign different variable names , Using Loops, Functions .

```
import pandas as pd
import sqlalchemy
from bokeh.plotting import figure, curdoc
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource
import time 

MYSQLHOST = "localhost"
MYSQLUSER = "toufik"
MYSQLPASSWORD = "toufik"
MYSQLDATABASE = "kraken_data"
uri = f"mysql+mysqlconnector://{MYSQLUSER}:{MYSQLPASSWORD}@{MYSQLHOST}/{MYSQLDATABASE}"
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine(uri)
query = sqlalchemy.text('SELECT * FROM kraken_trades')
with engine.connect() as connection:
    result = connection.execute(query)
    df = pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall(), columns=result.keys())
df['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df['time'])
df.set_index('id', inplace=True)

source = ColumnDataSource(data={'id': df.index, 'time': df['time'], 'price': df['price']})
tools = "pan,box_zoom,reset,save,xbox_select"
p = figure(title="Real-Time Bitcoin Price", x_axis_type='datetime', height=650, width=1350, tools=tools)
# Original data source line
line_rend = p.step(x='time', y='price', source=source, mode="after", line_width=2, color='navy')
line_rend.selection_glyph = line_rend.glyph
line_rend.nonselection_glyph = line_rend.glyph
# Now make a scatter renderer with zero alpha driving off the same ColumnDataSource
scatter_rend = p.scatter('time','price', fill_alpha=0, source=source, line_alpha=0)
scatter_rend.selection_glyph = scatter_rend.glyph
scatter_rend.nonselection_glyph = scatter_rend.glyph

df_cum = pd.DataFrame()
first_id = None

def box_select_callback(attr, old_indices, new_indices):
    
    global first_id
    if new_indices:
    
        selected_i = [source.data['id'][i] for i in new_indices]
        selected_x = [source.data['time'][i] for i in new_indices]
        selected_y = [source.data['price'][i] for i in new_indices]

        # Convert the selected data to a DataFrame
        df_range = pd.DataFrame({'id': selected_i, 'time': selected_x, 'price': selected_y})
        df_range.set_index('time', inplace=True)

        max_price = df_range['price'].idxmax()
        min_price = df_range['price'].idxmin()
        
        if max_price < min_price : 
            
            diff_1 =  (max_price - df_range.iloc[0].name).total_seconds()
            diff_2 =  (df_range.iloc[-1].name - min_price).total_seconds()
            
            if diff_1 <  diff_2 :
                
                pivot_time = min_price
                pivot_id = df_range.loc[min_price]['id']
                pivot_price = df_range.loc[min_price]['price']
                
            else:  
                
                pivot_time = max_price
                pivot_id = df_range.loc[max_price]['id']
                pivot_price = df_range.loc[max_price]['price']
                
        elif min_price < max_price :
            
            diff_1 = ( min_price- df_range.iloc[0].name).total_seconds()  
            diff_2 =  (df_range.iloc[-1].name - max_price).total_seconds()
            
            if diff_1 <  diff_2 :
                
                pivot_time = max_price
                pivot_id = df_range.loc[max_price]['id']
                pivot_price = df_range.loc[max_price]['price']
                
            else:  
                
                pivot_time = min_price 
                pivot_id = df_range.loc[min_price]['id']
                pivot_price = df_range.loc[min_price]['price']
                
        first_id = pivot_id - 1
        print('new first_id :',first_id)
        
        def update_chart_2():
    
            global first_id, df_cum
    
                with engine.connect() as connection:
        
                    query = sqlalchemy.text('SELECT * FROM kraken_trades WHERE id >= :first_id LIMIT 3')
                    result = connection.execute(query, {'first_id': int(first_id)})
                    df_2 = pd.DataFrame(result.fetchall(), columns=result.keys())
                    df_2['time'] = pd.to_datetime(df_2['time'])
                    df_2.set_index('time', inplace=True)
        
                    if not df_2.empty :
                
                        if not df_2.isna().values.any():
                
                            first_id = df_2.iloc[-1]['id'] + 1  # Set first_id to the last 'id' in df data
                
                            df_cum = pd.concat([df_cum, df_2])
                    
        curdoc().add_periodic_callback(update_chart_2, 5000)
        
# Attach the Python callback to the figure's selected attribute
source.selected.on_change('indices', box_select_callback)
                        
curdoc().add_root(p)
```